# curl - params with backslash don't go through

Tags: curl

Working on a Windows environment

I can do this command with wget, and it works:

`wget --method GET  "http://localhost/command?folderSource=\\myshare\myfolder&folderDestination=\\myshare\myfolder"`

But the below curl command gives an error on the server: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986

`curl --request GET "http://localhost:8090/command?folderSource=\\myshare\myfolder&folderDestination=\\myshare\myfolder"`

I've narrowed it down to the parameters having backslashes... Without backslashes, both params are received fine by the server. I've tried escaping the backslashes with additional backslashes... I've tried adding one, two, and three,,,, No luck. I've also tried URL-encoding the param-values with no luck. Would appreciate help on how I can pass a param containing a backslash with curl on Windows

Comment: This question is more about your java server than curl or Windows. It would seem url encoding is the way, check out what it says [here](https://programmer.help/blogs/characters-are-defined-in-rfc-7230-and-rfc-3986.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that led me to discover using the param --data-urlencode, which worked!